# Change the href attribute of the submenus' titles in the jQuery.mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I am using the *mmenu* in my website. I need to **change the link of the submenus titles** (the titles in each section that look like this `<a class="mm-title" href="#">Grades</a>` ). Usually when you click on one of this it show you the previous section in the menu. What I need is it to redirect to a page in the web, not to the menu. I have tried to give each `span.header-lateral-link` a `data-target-link` attribute with the url of the page I want it to redirect, but it is not working.

This is the html code:

```
<span class="header-lateral-link" data-target-link="http://www.google.es"><span class="icon-school"></span>Grades</span>
```

And this is the js code:

```
$('span.header-lateral-link').each(function() {
    var pageLink = $(this).data('target-link');
    var titleText = $(this).text();
    $('a.mm-title:contains(titleText)').attr('href', pageLink);
});
```

Thank you!

---

More information

the thing is that when I create the menu in html, I do it using lists. I write the title of the submenu using a span and the jQuery.mmenu.js plugin transform this span to create a element a.mm-title which is the title of the submenu. I have been able to add the same href to all of the titles, but I can´t give different href to each one. I have tried with that code but it does not work. If you know another way it could work, it´s ok. It is not necessary to use the code I wrote before.

Thanks!

Comment: i don't get it - you want to redirect after clicking on that `<span>` element?

Comment: not sure about this but try:

`$('span.header-lateral-link').each(function() {
    var pageLink = $(this).attr('data-target-link');
    var titleText = $(this).text();
    $('a.mm-title:contains(titleText)').attr('href', pageLink);
});`

Comment: can you please provide more detail.

Comment: the thing is that when I create the menu in html, I do it using lists. I write the title of the submenu using a span and the jQuery.mmenu.js plugin transform this span to create a element a.mm-title which is the title of the submenu. I have been able to add the same href to all of the titles, but I can´t give different href to each one. I have tried with that code but it does not work. If you know another way it could work, it´s ok. It is not necessary to use the code I wrote before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that 'data-target-link="http://www.google.es"' should be retrieved like:
 var pageLink = $(this).data('targetLink');

See [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

Comment: I have tried it but the results are the same as before... Any other idea?

Comment: give this line a try: $('a.mm-title:contains("'+titleText+'")').attr('href', pageLink);